# App crashed after deployment Heroku Play! Framework (type double does not exist)

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I am not able to properly deploy my `Play Frmaework app` (Java) on Heroku by using a PostgreSQL database. 
 
**Procfile**

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/name -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
>   -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL

**built.sbt**:

```
name := """name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4"
```

**Heroku's logs**:

> ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.429517+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m @6m7pfofpb:
>   Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.412967+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [←[31merror←[0m]
>   play - ERROR: type "double" does not exist
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.412974+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Position: 320
>   [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42704] ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.428889+00:00
>   app[web.1]:←[0m Oops, cannot start the server.
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.429771+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.checkEvolutionsState(Evolutions.scala:196)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.429822+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.databaseEvolutions(Evolutions.scala:367)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.429871+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:332)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.429907+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$$anonfun$evolutionScript$2.apply(Evolutions.scala:330)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433005+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433063+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.evolutionScript(Evolutions.scala:330)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433140+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:486)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433214+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:531)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433254+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:485)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433294+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:483)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433333+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433450+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:483)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433528+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433588+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433676+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433728+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433774+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433809+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433864+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.433912+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.StaticApplication.(ApplicationProvider.scala:55)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434109+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:244)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434194+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:280)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434302+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:275)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434388+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434467+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:275)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:43.434565+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at
>   play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
>   ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:44.389152+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed
>   from starting to crashed ←[36m2015-05-20T13:35:44.376937+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 255

I especially do not understand this log line

> 00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [←[31merror←[0m] play - ERROR: type "double"
>   does not exist

Of course, I have some double attributes in some of my project class. Why is there an error on the double type?

Any advice/ideas more than welcome :)

**EDIT 1** 
Here are the only two classes where I use the `double` type. 
**Car**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id; 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_fk")
    private User user; 
    private String brand; 
    private String model; 
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String licencePlate; 
    private String fuel;
    private int nbSits; 
    @Column(name = "avg_cons", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double avgCons; // Average consumption
    @Column(name = "co2_cons", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double co2Cons;
    @Column(name = "htva_price", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double htvaPrice; 
    @Column(name = "leasing_price", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double leasingPrice;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double mileage; 
    @Column(columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private boolean availability;
}
```

**Transaction**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_fk")
    private Car car;
    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver")
    private User driver;  
    @Column(name = "from_date")
    private Timestamp fromDate; 
    @Column(name = "to_date")
    private Timestamp toDate; 
    @Column(name = "start_mileage", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double startMileage; 
    @Column(name = "end_mileage", columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double endMileage;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "REAL")
    private double avgCons; 
    private String status; 
    private boolean exchange; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the part of the DDL statement which issues this error. It should be in one of your evolutions *.sql files (probably 1.sql). And maybe also the corresponding Java model class

Comment: I will do it on Sunday since i have no computer access by then.

Comment: @Anton I did an update of my question. I take a look into 1.sql ans it is nothing more than than the classic create table script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL works with column types **double precision** and does not know the column type **double**

I would suggest to try something like

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC")
private BigDecimal startMileage;
```

the value of the `columnDefinition` is actually part of the DDL statement, that is why you should check your 1.sql to see what exactly is being generated (by Ebean)

Comment: Thank you very much, that does work. However, why can't I use double instead of BigDecimal?